# Why is `groupby` not returning a KeyError when a column is missing ? How to prevent values from beeing used as-is to determine the groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas
df_trade = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        "reporter": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "reporter_code": [1, 1, 2, 2],
        "partner": ["x", "y", "x", "z"],
        "partner_code": [24, 25, 24, 26],
        "product": ["p", "p", "p", "p"],
        "value": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
)
index = ['reporter', 'product', 'year', 'reporter_code']
df_trade.groupby(index).agg(imp=("value", sum)).reset_index()
--
Out[1]:
           index  imp
0        product    2
1       reporter    1
2  reporter_code    4
3           year    3
```

The "year" column is missing from `df_trade`, why is `groupby` not returning a KeyError?

## Documentation

help(df_trade.groupby):

> If a list or ndarray of length
> equal to the selected axis is passed (see the `groupby user guide <https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups>`_),
> the values are used as-is to determine the groups. A label or list
> of labels may be passed to group by the columns in `self`.

Maybe this is because my sample data frame just happens to have 4 rows, the exact same number as the 4 items in the  `index` list used for the groupby.

- How to prevent the values from being "used as-is to determine the groups"?

Comment: What's your expected behaviour ? Because the actual one is intentional (*see* [`GH52852`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52852)).

Comment: Thanks  a lot, I have the exact same question as in [pandas/issues/52852](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52852) "So I added something like label_name in df.columns check for now, but I'm curious if there's some better way."

Comment: Maybe I'm worrying to much about an issue which is likely to occur only in test datasets. In real cases, the number of `groupby` columns (typically a handful) is much smaller that the number of rows in the data frame (several thousands, millions or more).

Answer (score 0):

Raising the error in this way makes sure all index columns are present in the data frame

```
for col in index:
    if col not in df_trade.columns:
        raise KeyError(f"{col} column not found")
```

This is not a very satisfactory answer and I'm still wondering: Would it be possible to use pandas.groupby() in a way that it generates the error by itself in this case?